# How to stop default browser behavior of submitting form on click of enter?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
    $("#" + actName + "frmEmail" + clientUserId).submit(function (ex) {
            ex.preventDefault();
```

Comment: preventDefault() should do it fine.. what's wrong with what you posted?

Comment: Actually when submit calls it also fires client side events like which i had set in onclick of other buttons (which are in same form) which i dont want

Comment: Don't you think it would be relevant to tell us that?

Comment: Sorry my question was not specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eg:

```
 $("#" + actName + "frmEmail" + clientUserId).submit(function (ex) {
  if(...){
      ...;
  return false;
  }
 else{
  ...
  }

})
```

Comment: This will never submit, so even having the submit event is irrelevent

Comment: sorry, I know that, I mean if event callback raise error, then return false,it will not submit.

Comment: I know this but i want to stop calling other client side events, i know it is strange but its takes place when submit calls

Comment: I found solution via handling key press on form

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by handling key press event on form.
`$("#" + actName + "frmEmail" + clientUserId).keypress(function (e) {`
                `var key = e.which;`
                `if (key == 13)`

{
                   `return false;`
}
                `return true;`
});